# React - Animation won't play on state change

Tags: reactjs, animation

I believe similar question was asked multiple times and there are some articles describing how to solve the issue. Solutions I found don't work for me and I wonder if there is something basic I'm missing.

I have a component which receives an array of logs from the backend server (this is happening whenever certain buttons are clicked). What I want to show is a small animation played only on the newest log, to show that this log just appeared.

My first attempt was to use CSS: Animations and it did work, but only when I refreshed the page. One of the articles I found said this is the way React works. 
Someone solution suggested to remove the class name with the animation from the tag/component, but that didn't work. The result was exactly the same, animation played only once, and then nothing.

On second attempt I tried to use `react-animations` npm package, hoping that it will have some built-in logic to handle the issue with React not being to replay the same animation without refreshing the page. Same result, animation is only playing once.

Finally I used the `react-transition-group` npm package, which should solve the problem, but it doesn't work neither (I wonder if I'm actually missing anything here, with how it should be implemented). Again, animation is being played once, and then it doesn't play when new logs appear without refreshing the page.

Here is the code: (in `renderLogs()` the first element of the array gets the `styles.jello` style which is the animation

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Container, Row } from 'react-grid-system'
import { Card, CardHeader, CardBody } from 'reactstrap'
import { bounce, jello } from 'react-animations'
import { StyleSheet, css } from 'aphrodite'
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group'

export default class Logger extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            logs: []
        }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) => {
        this.setState({
            logs: nextProps.logs
        })
    }

    renderLogs = () => {
        return this.state.logs.map((x, i) => i === 0 ? (
            <CSSTransition timeout={500}>
                <p className={css(styles.jello, styles.pItalic)}>{x}</p>
            </CSSTransition>
        ) : <p className={css(styles.pItalic)}>{x}</p>)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Card className={css(styles.cardMain)}>
                        <CardHeader className={css(styles.amrcGradient, styles.whiteFont)}>
                            Logs
                    </CardHeader>
                        <CardBody className={css(styles.cardBody)}>
                            {this.renderLogs()}
                        </CardBody>
                    </Card>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    bounce: {
        animationName: bounce,
        animationDuration: '1s'
    },
    jello: {
        animationName: jello,
        animationDuration: '1s'
    },
    amrcGradient: {
        backgroundImage: 'linear-gradient(to right,#0053a1 0,#0099df 100%)',
        width: '100%'
    },
    whiteFont: {
        color: `white`
    },
    cardMain: {
        width: '100%',
        backgroundColor: '#ededed'
    },
    cardBody: {
        padding: '2px',
        maxHeght: '170px',
        overflow: 'auto'
    },
    pItalic: {
        fontStyle: 'italic'
    }
})
```

Any help is appreaciated!